# SQL Out parameter received as null while passing from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am trying to populate a value in an `out` parameter but it is returned as null from the stored procedure.

But it works fine when I try to run the query through SSMS.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_ABCD]
    (@signal_xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT)   -- this parameter includes the result in case
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @signal_data XML

    SET @signal_data = cast(@signal_xml as XML)

    INSERT INTO DBLog  
    VALUES ('USP_ABCD', 'test', @signal_xml, ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETUTCDATE())

    SET @signal_xml = 'ABCD';
END
```

C# code calling this stored procedure:

```
private static void runSP()
{
    try
    {
        var temp = File.ReadAllText(@"abcd\TEST1.txt");
        var conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

            // Setup the command to execute the stored procedure.
            command.CommandText = "dbo.USP_ABCD";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Set up the output parameter to retrieve the summary.
            SqlParameter paramSignalXml = new SqlParameter("@signal_xml", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
            paramSignalXml.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            paramSignalXml.Value = temp;
            command.Parameters.Add(paramSignalXml);

            // Execute the stored procedure.
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine((String)(paramSignalXml.Value));
            var retValue = (String)(paramSignalXml.Value);

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to pass value to output parameter or am I missing something? Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you're passing the parameter in C# looks okay, but if you're expecting `SET @signal_data = cast(@signal_xml as XML)` to operate on the value of `temp` assigned to the `Value` property, you need to use `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`. And then you need to use `@signal_data` in the `INSERT` statement. Even better, if `temp` contains XML, pass it as an XML parameter, and use another parameter as text output.

Comment: Your code seems okay. But you can try as `var retValue = Convert.ToString(paramSignalXml.Value);` .